# How can we save a timestamp with each row inserted into BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, timestamp, streaming

There is feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72080883#comment19) which asks this question but the best solution I could find over there is to "add a TIMESTAMP column in the table schema, and assign "AUTO" in your json payload. With "AUTO" key words, the system will set the column value to be the wall timestamp on behalf of the user"

Is there anyway to do this without changing the payload in anyway ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that at ingestion, you need to reprocess your data just after to do that.

---

However, you can cheat. You can create a [table partitioned by ingestion time](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#ingestion_time), because the timestamp that you want is the time at which the data has been inserted in BigQuery.

Then, when you query (or you can create a view) you can use the pseudo column `_PARTITIONTIME` to get that ingestion time value.

Comment: Unfortunately, the business logic requires the tables to be partitioned differently. The workaround I found out is to use the "AUTO" feature in the code itself to ingest a timestamp field to Bigquery. For example:  row.set("timestamp_field", "AUTO");